# Standalone creates extra empty page (MWE)

Tags: standalone, dvips

There are many images I want to generate separately and import into my main tex document using `\includegraphics`. However, using the standalone documentclass generates an extra blank page after the image produced. If I change to `\documentclass{article}` (which I do not want as it doesn't crop to the correct size of the image), there is no extra page.

Here is a minimum working example.

```tex
\documentclass{standalone} % \documentclass{article} doesn't produce extra empty page
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[label={left: $x$}] (x) at (0,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How do I generate the image without the extra page? I'm using the command `latexmk -dvi <imageName>.tex`

Notes:

- When opening the .dvi file, there is one page (with content), and a second empty page.
- I run `dvips <imageName>.dvi -o <imageName.eps`. When opening the .eps file, there is one page (with content), and a second empty page.
- I use `\includegraphics` to import the .eps file. This displays without issue in my main document, but the question remains open as to why the output .dvi file has two pages.

Comment: if I run the provided document with pdflatex I just get a single page. but as you say two with latex. hmmm

Comment: tested at overleaf it gives one page in texlive 2018 but two in texlives from 2019

Comment: Interesting, @DavidCarlisle. I tried `pdflatex -dvi <imageName>.tex` and still had an extra page. My latexmk version is 4.67 and pdflatex is 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020)

Comment: no I mean just use pdflatex not dvi (why do you want dvi?) that gives one page. The dvi route started giving two pages in texlive 2019 I'm not sure yet if latex or standalone chaneg is responsible

Comment: It's worth noting that when importing the image using `\includegraphics`, the extra page does not cause an issue. It displays the first page with the image as expected.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I would actually like an .eps, and the best route I know to go about that is `latexmk -dvi`, then `dvips` to produce an eps.

Comment: you have not shown how you are importing the image. latex can not include dvi files so you must presumably be transforming the dvi to something else, that probably drops the second page

Comment: it would be simpler to use pdflatex here and for your main document and then you could just directly include the pdf.

Comment: I have been noticing this for a while too. Interestingly, `dvilualatex`+`dvips` produces a single page

Comment: use `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}` or `\standaloneenv{tikzpicture}`. Then the environment is correctly setup.

Answer (score 2):

The solution from [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) in comments worked:

> use `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}` or `\standaloneenv{tikzpicture}`.
> Then the environment is correctly setup.